# How do I display the correct amount of nodes on a view?

Tags: views, 8

I have a content type called "spotlight". It's just a box that sits at the bottom of each page with related content inside of it. I have the view set up correctly to display 4 items (because that is the max per row and I only want 1 row) and it displays perfectly on the front page, displaying 4 spotlights.

Now on my other page I only want to display 3 spotlights. I add only three and leave the last one blank. Instead of displaying 3 spotlights, it displays the 3 spotlights I called out then repeats the first one again.

It's almost like if I still only added 3 spotlights but set the pager to display 150 items, it would just display those same 3 over and over 50 times in a row.

Comment: Matt, welcome to the community!. Are you using some javascript code in the front-end to enhance your block? It seems to me like the kind of bug that would arise from a slider component that is supposed to work only in mobile, but that spills over to the desktop version in this weird way.

Comment: Simply create two different blocks, one for the front page limited to show 4 items, one for all other pages to show 3 items, place both blocks and edit their visibility settings, done, move on. :)